# git push says Everything up to date

Tags: ios, xcode, git, version-control, github

I am having trouble understanding the concept of git local and remote versioning. For example I have a iPhone app in a local git rep. Initally this was my master branch. I then checked out a new branch `git checkout -b "update-2.0.1"`.

Then I set `git push origin update-2.0.1` to ensure that I have a seperate branch for developing this app update and when done merge it back into my master branch. Fine!

Now that I am on my update-branch I want to create branches for every issue ID. So I say `git checkout -b "#3178"` - when I now try to push this new issue-branch in my remote repository git says `"Everything-up-to-date"`.

I don't see why it is not possible to push this issue branch to the remote repository?

`git remote -b` returns

> origin/master
>
> origin/update-2.0.1

I would love to see a third branch

> origin/update-2.0.1/#3178

Comment: have you committed anything into this new branch? It is probably empty.

Comment: it is empty but the update-2.0.1 was empty as well and git pushed it to the remote. Now it can't...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the new branch was not pushed into the remote repository was simply because I did not use the double quotes.

```
git push origin "new-branch"
```

Also when renaming branches always use the double quotes - at least in my case it worked while not all code samples in the web use this syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You need to repeat the first command:

```
git push origin <name-of-branch>
```

to create the corresponding remote branch for every new branch you create locally. Git won't push unless it has somewhere to push to. This can be an empty branch if that's what you need.

You would then end up with

```
origin/<name-of-branch>
```

and not

```
origin/<name-of-branch>/<name-of-other-branch>
```

Although they will be listed without a hierarchy, they do in fact branch off each other. Use gitk or something to view the history log visually to confirm this.

If you want to finish working on the issue and merge it into the branch it started from, do this:

```
git checkout <name-of-original-branch> // update-2.0.1
git merge --no-ff <name-of-finished-branch> // #3178
git push origin // Will write local update-2.0.1 to origin
```

Check out [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) if you want a nice visual explanation of why using the --no-ff option is a very powerful model for tracking branches that come off other branches as part of your release cycle.

Comment: I think I get your point and that's the way it works. On the other hand I thought I could push the issue-branch without any commits to make other team members work on it without naming it. I just see two of the same processes (pushing an empty update-branch and pushing an empty issue-branch) with two different results.

Comment: You can push an empty branch using the first command above. I slightly garbled that bit. Edited to amend.

Comment: It it still not working. I was working on branch #3178 commited my work and wanted to `git push origin #3178` still with the same result `Everything-up-to-date`

Comment: What sequence of commands did you use to commit? Remember you need git add first.

Comment: yeah I added everything first `git add .` then commited `git commit -m "whatever message"` and then `git push origin #3178` result: `Everything up-to-date` - when I do a `git status` i says "nothing to commit (working directory clean)" .. I am really not sure if Xcode messes somthing up...

Comment: Change a file, then do git status. You should see it marked as altered. Does this happen?

Comment: Yes it does happen. I just altered 2 files and added 2 new files and I can see that when I type `git status`

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the branch you want to merge for example go to "master" and merge your other branch **update-2.0.1** to the master.

```
git checkout master
git merge update-2.0.1
git push
```

for example. Then you have all changes from the update branch in the master branch and you can push this.

When you really need only a new branch then make only

```
git branch name
```

from the branch you are at this time. When you push it to origin you have a new **remote branch**

check it with

```
git branch -r #remote branches
git branch #local branches
```